# How to write data to JSON file while using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, database, reactjs

Or actually the question should be

> How to write data to JSON file using Reactjs and Nodejs

I'm very first to react and do not understand which database should I use with.

PS. It's can easily to read json file with

`var data = require('./data.json');`

but to write data I try using npm '**jsonfile**' package and both try to used Nodejs 
and got this error

`TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function`

Comment: Could you include the complete code?

Comment: If you're trying to access your filesystem/database directly from your front-end React app, that's not going to work. You need to communicate with a server via HTTP, and then have the server do the stuff that interacts with the files/database.

Answer (score 1):

I was literally searching for an answer on this today. I'm using React so it should be similiar for you. I think I figured it out.

I found you have to do two things.

1. Import the Json file at the top of your code file

   import data from ./data.json
2. Declare a variable passing the name of the variable specified in the import statement(in this case data)

   const data = require('./data.json');

Now calling {data} should allow you to usae the data of the file

Hope this helps :D